# How long after fixing a crawl error in Bing Webmaster Tools before Bing recrawls and stops showing the error?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

When will Bing recrawl my online shopping site?

Yesterday I solved my site errors that were displayed in in Bing Webmaster Tools.  I asked it to fetch those URLs.  Bing webmaster tools still shows the error for my site.

When will crawl and index my site now that there are no errors?  How much time do I need to wait?

Comment: I don't pay too much attention to Bing, so I'm not 100% sure.   I would expect Google to take 2 to 4 weeks in a similar situation.   I'll bet that it will be about the same for Bing.

Answer (score 1):

Bing, like Google, indexes sites at variable intervals depending on how important it perceives a site to be.  So wait times could be as little as one day and as long as several weeks.

I would give it a month to 6 weeks before panicking.